Intuition behind the explicit null homotopy for showing that going around once and then again in opposite direction is homotopic to a point
I am reading this answer where the following homotopy is given to show that goign around the circle once in one direction and then in the opposite direction is homotopic to the constant.

Given a path $\gamma(t)$ then $\gamma(st)$ is a nulhomotopy retracting the curve to the start point. The reversed path (starting from the retracted endpoint) is given by $\gamma(s(1-t))$. These can then be concatenated at time $t$ to give
$$
h(s,t) = \begin{cases} \gamma(2st) & 0\leq t \leq 0.5 \\ \gamma(2s(1-t)) & 0.5 \leq t \leq 1\end{cases}
$$

My question is, how does one come up with such a homotopy? I don't see what the intuition behind the construction is?

Think of a rubber band. Loop it around your two index fingers, then pull your fingers apart to stretch the rubber band. The rubber band backtracks around one finger, goes to the other finger, backtracks around that other finger, and back to the first finger.
Now abstract this situation. Imagine stretching the band along the segment $[0,1]$. The band goes forward from $0$ to $1$ along the segment, and then backwards from $1$ to $0$. Note that the rubber band backtracks at $0$, and it also backtracks at $1$.
One can then relax the rubber band, holding the backtracking point at $0$ rigidly in position, but allowing the backtracking point at $1$ to retract backwards all the way along $[0,1]$ towards $0$.
Now imagine that the segment $[0,1]$ is itself stretched along some path $\gamma$. Well, that doesn't make any difference to the rubber band, it is happy to be constrained to follow the path. One can still imagine the rubber band stretching along the path $\gamma$ from the initial point $\gamma(0)$ to the terminal point $\gamma(1)$, with backtracking around both of those points. And then one can imagine relaxing the rubber band, holding the initial backtracking point at $\gamma(0)$ rigidly in position, but allowing the terminal backtracking point at $\gamma(1)$ to retract backwards all the way along $\gamma$ towards $\gamma(0)$.
Now use your training from analytic geometry to write equations expressing all of this. You will get the formula for $h(s,t)$.
